# Using selfdestruct in constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-development, fallback-function

What's the purpose of such a call to this stub?

```
contract Sacrifice {
    constructor(address payable _recipient) payable {
        selfdestruct(_recipient);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if (_token == address(0)) {
    if (!_to.send(_amount)) {
            (new Sacrifice).value(_amount)(_to);
}
```

**Compiler error:**

```
CompileError: /token/contracts/EasyStaking.sol:313:17: TypeError: Member "call" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (address payable) payable returns (contract Sacrifice). Did you intend to call the function?
                (new Sacrifice).call(_amount)(_to);
                ^------------------^
```

**Fixed it with this:**

```
        if (_token == address(0)) {
            if (!_to.send(_amount)) { // solium-disable-line security/no-send
                (new Sacrifice){value: _amount}(_to);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you're asking about the usage of a code, or about a compilation error.

Comment: Plus, from the compilation error itself, it seems that it is relevant to some other code (i.e., not the code your question).

Comment: @goodvibration I'd like to talk about this idiom which is used here. Though the ```call``` syntax I don't understand too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `selfdestruct` forcibly transfers the contract's balance to the target address.

The code first tries `_to.send(_amount)` to transfer ethers. If the fallback function revers `send` will return false. In case of failure it uses new/selfdestruct to inconditionaly transfer ethers to the target addres.