# Using `selfdestruct()` to send back funds to stakers

Tags: solidity

Currently, I deploy a contract via a Factory contract for staking. Think of it like UniSwap pools without swapping, short term contracts that I want to destroy after their use is done. But I also want to reimburse the original stakers and distribute the rewards post staking. What is the logic I should be using here? The one idea I had was use a specific reimburse function - and then destroy the contract. Any better ideas?

Comment: Maybe relevant for this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91453/using-selfdestruct-in-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's much safer to let the users pull the rewards (and their stakes), instead of you pushing them.

I don't also see much point in destroying the contract. Just leave it there and users can come and claim their assets whenever they want - maybe tomorrow or maybe in 10 years.